# Windows Install and Diskpart Failing To Interact With Drive

Tags: windows-10, diskpart

I am trying to install windows 10 on a laptop. The partitions are listed in the installer and installing on all of them fails as well as deleting them. They cannot be deleted or modified in diskpart either (returns 'IO DEVICE ERROR'). How can I override all these warnings from only the windows install disk and install windows?

Comment: Try a third-party tool such as DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/. Also, you cannot modify a mounted partition... boot from USB.

Comment: It is being booted from the install USB. Do I need to manually unmount partitions in DP?

Comment: I already stated I’m booting from install disc - X:.